# App compiles and runs fine, apk builds fine, but IDE says sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio keeps telling me sync failed, the messages window is empty, the gradle console is empty. When I press the button to compile and install, that works fine. I can even build an apk and the apk works fine.

Sync was working fine until a couple of days ago I got a notice that some components had updates, I didn't pay much attention to what was updating. Then this issue started. I usually keep my Android Studio (3.0.1) fairly up to date so it was probably a very recently released update of some component. I'm running this on Ubuntu. I also have another project that shares pretty much every module except for the App module with this one and it doesn't have this issue.

What can I do to figure out why the sync is failing?

Edit: I should probably add that I've done multiple cleans and invalidate and restart.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.gradle/` . and the same for the project gradle folder and restart the project

Comment: No luck, same issue. It is just so strange that the app will run fine, build the apk fine, but it keeps saying sync failed and doesn't give me any info about why.

Comment: Deleting the `.idea` directory seems to have fixed it. I will monitor it for a couple more days to see if that really fixes it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by removing the `.idea` directory.